# Fourier coefficient and computing an improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, closed-form

I am having difficulties with this problem. I don't really know where to start, I suspect there is something I am supposed to know or "see" that I am missing.

$u$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function defined by

$$u(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{\sin x}{x} & 0 \lt |x| \lt \pi \\
      1 & x = 0 .
   \end{cases}$$

Show that the Fourier coefficients of $u$ are given by

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$$

and use this to compute the improper integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}.$$

Trying to compute the Fourier coefficients the way I normally would is messy since $\frac{sinx}{x}$ doesn't "disappear" when doing partial integration. Also, the bounds are confusing me.

Then I thought maybe I could use that

$$u(0) = 1 = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} c_n,$$ and
$$u(\pi) = \frac{\sin \pi}{\pi} = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{in\pi},$$

but after that I am stuck again.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. The given function is even, then you just have to consider
$$
\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin x}{x}\:\cos (nx)\:dx, \quad n\ge0,
$$ one may recall that
$$
\sin a \cos b=\frac12\left(\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b) \right),
$$ then use a change of variable to get
$$
\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx.
$$